# How to delete my favorites?

Tags: support, bookmarks

I specify lots of question as my favorites without attention. Now my favorites become useless and unmanageable. I wish to find any way to delete them all and start to make as favorites with more attention for the next time in order to do a better search between them. So is there any way to undo favorites?

Comment: Are you just asking how to remove one question from your favourites or all at once? For one, it's simple, just click the star to undo.

Comment: @LiveWireBT I want to remove all of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "bulk" way of removing favorites, but there is a way which is somewhat easy.

Go to your [favorites page](https://askubuntu.com/users/current?tab=favorites), and click on the favorite icon of each question one by one. At least you won't have to go into the question's page each time.

Comment: I was kind of sure that the api provides a way to do this.